# Converting a UTC Time to Epoch format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, python-datetime

I'm trying to convert a specific UTC time & date to seconds since the Epoch; however, I have not been able to figure out how to do this since I am not in the UTC time zone.

I tried using the datetime module to convert a date & time to seconds since the epoch, but python has been using my system's local time so the returned value is off by 7 hours. I understand that I could simply subtract 7*60 so that it would work in my time zone; however, I need this to work in multiple time zones without hardcoding the time change into my program.

This works except it uses the system time (MST), but I am looking for a solution that is specifically UTC time. Note the variables defined here represent an example of a time in UTC that I am trying to convert to seconds since the epoch.

```py
import datetime

year=2019
month=5
day=9
hour=21
minute=45

Time=datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute).timestamp()
print(Time)
```

Output:

```
1557463500.0
```

Desired output (7 hours earlier):

```
1557438300.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import datetime

year=2019
month=5
day=9
hour=21
minute=45

e = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)
t = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute)
print((t-e).total_seconds())
```

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good enough. I am a beginner of English, a beginner of here:)

Answer (score 0):

You can caclulate the timestamp of epoch date using `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0).timestamp()` and then subtract your current timestamp from it

```
import datetime

year=2019
month=5
day=9
hour=21
minute=45

#Date timestamp
dt_timestamp=datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute).timestamp()

#Epoch timestamp
epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0).timestamp()

#Epoch
print(dt_timestamp-epoch)
```

The output will be

```
1557438300.0
```

Comment: Hi @DavidSchwartz, I saw you accepted and then unaccepted my answer :) Was something missing my answer. If you could let me know, I can fix it :)